# Moving a 3-D Object Along a Path in MatLab

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d

So I have an object, and I applied a rotation to it and I am curious as to how to get it to move along a path. I'm still learning MatLab, so if you see anything where I could/should do something different please let me know.
Any help is appreciated.

```
kittyx = [0 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150  -150 150 150 -150 -150 ...
    150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 ...
    -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 ...
    -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 -150 150 150 -150 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 ...
    150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 ...
    150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230 ...
    150 150 230 150 150 230 150 150 230];
kittyy = [0 0  0  1 1 2  2  3 3 4  4  5 5 6  6  7  7  7.5  7.5 8  8  8.5 8.5 9  9  9.5  9.5 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10 ...
    10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9.5 9.5 9 9 8.5 8.5 8 8 7.5 7.5 7 7 6 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 0 0 -1 -1 -2 -2 ...
    -3 -3 -4 -4 -5 -5 -6 -6 -7 -7 -7.5 -7.5 -8 -8 -8.5 -8.5 -9 -9 -9.5 -9.5 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 ...
    -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -9.5 -9.5 -9 -9 -8.5 -8.5 -8 -8 -7.5 -7.5 -7 -7 -6 -6 -5 -5 -4 -4 -3 -3 -2 -2 -1 -1 0 0 0 -7 0 7 6.5 0 6 5.5 0 ...
    5 4.5 0 4 3.5 0 3 2.5 0 2 1.5 0 1 0.5 0 0 -.5 0 -1 -1.5 0 -2 -2.5 0 -3 -3.5 0 -4 -4.5 0 -5 -5.5 0 -6 -6.5 0 ... 
    -7 -6.5 0 -6 -5.5 0 -5 -4.5 0 -4 -3.5 0 -3 -2.5 0 -2 -1.5 0 -1 -.5 0 0 .5 0 1 1.5 0 2 2.5 0 3 3.5 0 4 4.5 0 ...
    5 5.5 0 6 6.5 0 7 7.5 0];
kittyz = [6 6  6  5 5 4  4  3 3 2  2  1 1 0  0 -1 -1 -2   -2  -3 -3 -4  -4  -5 -5 -6   -6  -7 -7 -8 -8 -9 -9 -10 -10 -11 -11 -12 -12 -13 -13 ...
    -14 -14 -15 -15 -16 -16 -17 -17 -18 -18 -19 -19 -20 -20 -21 -21 -22 -22 -23 -23 -24 -24 -25 -25 -26 -26 -27 -27 -28 -28 -29 -29 -30 -30 -29 -29 -28 -28 ...
    -27 -27 -26 -26 -25 -25 -24 -24 -23 -23 -22 -22 -21 -21 -20 -20 -19 -19 -18 -18 -17 -17 -16 -16 -15 -15 -14 -14 -13 -13 -12 -12 -11 -11 -10 -10 ...
    -9 -9 -8 -8 -7 -7 -6 -6 -5 -5 -4 -4 -3 -3 -2 -2 -1 -1 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 -6 -6 -6 -5 -6 -4 -3 -6 ...
    -2 -1 -6 0 1 -6 2 3 -6 4 5 -6 6 7 -6 8 7 -6 6 5 -6 4 3 -6 2 1 -6 0 -1 -6 -2 -3 -6 -4 -5 -6 ...
    -6 -5 -6 -7 -8 -6 -9 -10 -6 -11 -12 -6 -13 -14 -6 -15 -16 -6 -17 -18 -6 -19 -20 -6 -20 -19 -6 -18 -17 -6 -16 -15 -6 -14 -13 -6 ...
    -12 -11 -6 -10 -9 -6 -8 -7 -6];

figure(1)
axis([-200 200 -200 200 -200 200])
hold on
%plot3(kittyx,kittyy,kittyz);
%Rotation Part
object = [kittyx
    kittyy
    kittyz];
v=.2;

for t=0:.1:4*pi

 x = -1*sin(t);
 y = 1*cos(t);
 pitch_angle = atan2(y,t)/sqrt((x/t)^2+(y/t)^2);
 yaw_angle = atan2(y,t)/(x/t);
 R = [cos(pitch_angle) 0 -sin(pitch_angle); 0 1 0; sin(pitch_angle) 0 cos(pitch_angle)];
 R2 = [cos(yaw_angle) -sin(yaw_angle) 0; sin(yaw_angle) cos(yaw_angle) 0; 0 0 1];
 object_pitched = R*(object);
 object_yawed = R2*(object_pitched);
 i = object_yawed(1,:);
 j = object_yawed(2,:);
 k = object_yawed(3,:);

view(45,45)
axis equal
%Plot and set axis
 plot3(i,j,k)
 axis([-200 200 -200 200 -200 200])
 pause(0.2);
 clf;

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just add/subtract some values to the object coordinates. In your example, you can add `t*100` to the x-corrdinate of the rotated object. This will translate the object to the right.

```
plot3(i+t*100,j,k);
```

You can also store the values of the path in vectors so that the object will follow its pre-defined route.

```
plot3( i + predifined_x(t), j, k);
```

where `predifined_x` is a vector of length `0:.1:4*pi`.